# How to solve mul wit byte memsize and gain 2 byte answer. asm a51

Tags: assembly, 8051

In my program i need make mul with 2 variable.
Memsize is only 1 byte.
For example:

First = 63h

Second = 64h

Result is more then 1 byte. How can i make mul?
'helps Devolus'
Okay. Mul is simple. What about div
If I have 270F / 64. How can i do it with only 1 byte mem size?

Comment: This is currently unanswerable. What CPU architecture? Don't you have an instruction set reference? (if not, try to find one). If the CPU lacks a multiplication instruction you can do addition in a loop.

Comment: @Michael, Obviously it's 8051 assembly.

Comment: Then the OP should have tagged it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mul ab
```

The value from the akkumulator is multiplied with the value in register B. The lower byte from the result is in the akkumulator and the higher byte is in B. So you must store your values appropriately.

So in your example `64h * 63h = 26ACh` in Register B you will have `26` and in the akkumulator you will have `AC`.

Comment: If the answer is helpfull, you should upvote it or mark it as correct. ;)

Comment: BTW: `div` works the same way, but you should google for 8051 instructon set, because you will also want to know about the flags and how they are affected. And you shouldn't edit your original question and add additional questions.

Comment: Okey. I find all i need.